# Translating routes in Rails 3.1 without any gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, routes

In a previous Rails 2.3 project I used the translate_routes gem to perform the translation of the routes. It worked great.
In my new Rails 3.1 project, again, I need route translation. Unfortunately, translate_routes doesn't work any longer and Raul its developer announced that he would no longer maintain the gem. 
I tried to work with one of the project's fork that is supposed to be ok on Rails 3.1, but I couldn't do much of it.

Is there a way to build route translations without a gem ?

Here an example of a working route without translation.

```
  constraints(:subdomain => 'admin') do
    scope "(:locale)", :locale => /fr|de/ do
           resources :country, :languages
          match '/' => 'home#admin', :as => :admin_home
    end
  end
```

As you can see, I also want to have a default route without locale that is used for my default locale : en.

Has anyone done that before?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a little bit late for you, but it may be helpful for others, try a fork of translate_routes:

https://github.com/francesc/rails-translate-routes

Comment: Thanks francesc. I'll give it a try an get back to you. I don't really like the solution I've set up so far. I used translate routes in rails 2.3 and it was a perfect fit.

Comment: I've been testing the gem on Rails 3.2, it works great, but it doesnt't seem to take subdomains into account.

Comment: I adapted your code to pass the subdomain to the translated routes and it works now. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Saw your post earlier, but found out another sollution later.
I wanted to translate Rails routes and their default resource actions, but I didn't like they way `rails-translate-routes` added `_nl` to my default path-names.

I ended up doing this (also works in rails 4.0), which should be a good sollution when you are presenting your app in only 1 or 2 languages.

```
# config/routes.rb
Testapp::Application.routes.draw do
  # This scope changes resources methods names
  scope(path_names: { new: I18n.t('routename.new'), edit: I18n.t('routename.edit') }) do

    # devise works fine with this technique
    devise_for :users, path: I18n.t('routename.userspath')

    # resource path names can be translated like this
    resources :cars, path: I18n.t('routename.carspath')

    # url prefixes can be translated to
    get "#{I18n.t('routename.carspath')}/export", to: 'cars#export'

  end
end
```

And

```
# config/locales/nl.yml
nl:
  routename:
    ## methods
    new: 'nieuw'
    edit: 'aanpassen'
    ## resources, etc.
    userpath: 'gebruikers'
    carspath: 'voertuigen'
```

Result in:

- /voertuigen

  - /voertuigen/nieuw
  - /voertuigen/aanpassen
  - /voertuigen/export

update and destroy are not neccesairy since they link into the root as post actions. Save your work ;)

Comment: Don't forget to reload routes `YourAppName::Application.reload_routes!` after user change language.